# Mostrar datos de Firebase en TableView Swift 4

Tags: firebase, swift, swift4, uitableview

tengo el siguiente JSON en Firebase y pretendo mostrar estos datos en un UITABLEVIEW

[image: Tengo mi rama principal llamada **CrudPrincipal** y de ahí se guardan distintos campos]

Para mostrarlos en mi TableView tengo el siguiente código:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var postDataRef = [String]()
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        databaseHandle = ref.child("CrudPrincipal").observe(.childAdded) { (DataSnapshot) in
            let crudOne = DataSnapshot.value as? String
            if let actualInfo = crudOne {
                self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postDataRef.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = postDataRef[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

.

Inserta los datos pero no los muestra en mi TableView

.

[image: Emulador]

¿Qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estas tratando de forma incorrecta el valor del dataSnapshot

```
dataSnapshot.value
```

En tu caso es de tipo Diccionario [String: String], porque solo tienes strings como valores.

Entonces la solución sería la siguiente:

```
let crudOne = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: String]
if let actualInfo = crudOne["Name"] as? String {
            self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

En este caso buscas la clave "Name" en tu diccionario y obtienes su valor que es tipo String.
Espero te sirva.